# Can I have emacs automatically indent my whole code after it is all written?

Tags: emacs

My `emacs` is set up to automatically indent my code as I write it and also re-indent things correctly if I push tab on any line that got misaligned somehow (usually because I changed the code). I am wondering, though, if there is any command in `emacs` that would allow me to take an entire file (with a code written in it) and indent the whole thing automatically the same way it normally indents my code real time as I write it without me having to go through and push tab on every line of the file?

I suppose I could define a macro that tabs and then advances to the next line and repeat that macro for the length of my file. I am wondering though if there is any command in `emacs` or some other feature that would do this automatically.

Comment: As a side note, there's a fairly new Stack Exchange site for emacs: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can indent the region, to do this for the whole buffer:

- mark whole buffer with `C-x h` (or `M-x mark-whole-buffer`)
- run indent region with `C-M-\` (or `M-x indent-region`)

Comment: If programming in Fortran (at least with `f90-mode`), `C-M-q` will indent the current program scope (subroutine, module, file, etc).

Comment: `C-M-q` works in all the C-family modes as well, and I think is a recommended keybinding for programming modes in general.

Comment: How would one change the behavior of `C-M-\\`, say to make it indent 4 spaces instead of 2?